# Bokeh not showing plots

Tags: python, bokeh

I'm designing a template for a bokeh plot that updates periodically to show the new data in a file I'd be reading.

At the moment, I'm just using a simple generator that makes numpy arrays just to test the app.

However, nothing shows up in the browser when I execute `bokeh serve --show test.py`. I'm not sure how to proceed, since there are no errors. My attempt at debugging with a print statement shows that the callback isn't even working.

This particular test should make multiple histograms on the same figure at each update.

```
import numpy as np
from bokeh.io import curdoc
from bokeh.models import ColumnDataSource
from bokeh.plotting import figure

def histplot_updater(sources, data_stream):
    def updater():
        data = data_stream.next()
        print 'got data'
        for i in range(data.shape[1]):
            d = data[:, i]
            mind = np.min(d)
            maxd = np.max(d)
            step = max((maxd - mind) // 100, 1)
            hist, edges = np.histogram(d, density=True, bins=range(mind, maxd + 2, step))
            new_data = {'top': hist, 'left': edges[:-1], 'right': edges[1:]}
            sources[i].data = new_data
    return updater

def init_histplot(f, data, **kwargs):
    hs = []
    ss = []
    for i in range(data.shape[1]):
        source = ColumnDataSource(dict(top=[], left=[], right=[]))
        kwgs = {k: v[i] for k,v in kwargs.items()}
        h = f.quad(top='top', bottom=0, left='left', right='right', source=source, **kwgs)
        hs.append(h)
        ss.append(source)
    return hs, ss

if __name__ == '__main__':
    fig = figure()
    Data = (np.random.normal([0, 1], [1, 2],  (1000, 2)) for i in xrange(100))

    h_sources = init_histplot(fig, Data)[1]
    curdoc().add_root(fig)
    curdoc().add_periodic_callback(histplot_updater(h_sources), 1000)
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tested and none of your code executes unless you remove:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
```

I'm guessing that bokeh doesn't run the same way as a standard program. If you remove that then you start getting errors, namely

```
Error running application handler <bokeh.application.handlers.script.ScriptHandler object at 0x7fed2cc1a590>: 'generator' object has no attribute 'shape'
```

Comment: Great, now I can start debugging. Any ideas about why it works like that?

Comment: I'm not sure, my best guess is that the main is on bokeh's side and then it calls our code so we're not technically writing the main